# The meaning of Data Modeling in case of noSql

Tags: database-design, nosql

I learned about data modeling layers (conceptual/logical/physical). I would like to understand how does the modeling process work on non-relational schemas.

1. Is there a need to "Normalize" the model when we using a NoSQL database?
2. Is the data model relevant when "Schema on reading"/flex schema?
3. I feel that the traditional data modeling concept is built for the relational schema. Is the process different when designing a data model for other data structures?

Answer (score 2):

You don't do data modelling to appease Codd; you do it to ensure that you understand your data and that the data stored in and retrieved from your database is complete, consistent, non-redundant, and compliant with business rules. The fact that *some* NoSQL stores do not validate schemas does not give you a license to dump garbage into them.

"Schema on read" simply means that an application layer *other than* the database has to understand the schema, and a properly documented model is *the* way to communicate that knowledge to that layer's developers.

The above concerns the conceptual and logical modelling, but physical modelling is  a thing with NoSQL databases too. Consider CouchDB: you may not need to model "tables", but you still need to give some thought to how best implement partitioning, given your "schema-less" documents' contents and typical query patterns; what indexes you need; how to approach replication conflicts etc.

> Is there a need to "Normalize"

Not in the sense this term is used in relational modelling, but you *do* need some sort of analysis and synthesis applied to your model to avoid redundancy and inconsistency in your data.

> Is the data model relevant when "Schema on reading"

Of course it is -- to whoever is trying to make sense of the data. Even to simply *query* the data you need to understand the model. You are simply shifting this responsibility to a different application layer.

> Is the process different

Not much, if you're doing it right.

---

Here's an example of one [utterly non-relational data model](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/resourcelist.html), which has both relational and non-relational physical implementations.

Answer (score 0):

In most use cases, there will always be a **data model** involved at some point regardless if you choose to store your data in a **relational database management system (RDBMS)** or a **NoSQL database system**. The differences between these two types of systems regarding the concept of data modeling is *when* the **data model** comes into play.

With a **RDBMS**, usually the **data model** is defined upstream such that the database entity tightly resembles the **data model** itself. This is great in cases where the data doesn't necessarily need to be distributed across multiple systems and the consumers can all access it from the same centralized server, the **data model** is well defined, and it doesn't have a need to change at a high frequency.

With a **NoSQL system**, usually the **data model** is defined at the consumer of the data, e.g. in the application layer, as concrete objects. This is great in cases where the data needs to be distributed across multiple systems (such as a mobile application that needs to support data manipulation offline), and multiple versions of that schema can exist between each of those distributed systems. A mobile application is a good example where the same data can be distributed across multiple systems, as different versions, but still be well defined.

That should answer your second two questions, but to your first question about **normalization**, this really depends on your use case. **Normalization** is really a concept for how to structure data in a **RDBMS**, so I don't believe it concretely exists for **NoSQL** which is meant to support semi-structured / unstructured / variable structured data. That being said, in my opinion, I think it makes sense to aim to follow the loose design concepts of **normalization** when applicable to your use case, even if you store your data in a **NoSQL** system. Going back to my original point that with most use cases, the **data model** will exist, even if it's not concretely defined until the application layer, it makes the job of the consumers to define that data model easier if the entities from the database follow a **normalized** like structure, when possible, even in **NoSQL**.